# how do you set a dynamic variable to 0 if a record does not exist in a table for a specific date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I set the value of a dynamic variable to 0 if no record exists for a specific date range?In the below snippet I am retrieving a transaction count of confirmed prints for a specific date range. If no records exist in the in the table how can I make the dynamic variable's value = 0?

```
--ADJ-CHDC-CareHealth DiscountCard Count
            Select @SQLSG = N'Select @result = Count (tr.ConfirmedPrints) from ' + @TransactionRemote + ' tr with(nolock) left outer join location l with(nolock) on l.id = tr.LocationID
                left outer join program p with(nolock) on p.id = tr.programid 
                where ' + @PortalID + ' = l.portalID and transactiondate between'''  + convert(varchar(20),@SGStartDate,120) + ''' and ''' + convert(varchar(20),@EndDate,120) + '''' + 
                ' and l.istest=0 and tr.programID is not null and (p.programtype=''CHDC'' or p.name like ''%Adjudication Remu%'')' 
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQLSG,N'@result int OUTPUT', @result=@AdjudicatedTotalCount OUTPUT
            if (@AdjudicatedTotalCount > 0)  Set @SGProgramTypeDetails = @SGProgramTypeDetails + ' ADJ-CHDC=' + convert(varchar(10),@AdjudicatedTotalCount)+ ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern that you need:

```
Declare @result as int
Declare @Tablename as varchar(100)
Declare @sql as nvarchar(1100)

Set @Tablename = 'myTable'

set @sql = 'Select @result = count(*) from ' + @Tablename

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result int out', @result out

print @result
```

This uses a dynamic SQL and assigns the output of that to your already declared variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I already have the structure. For simplicity sake I only posted the block where I am having the issue. The problem that I am having is that if no records exist for a given date range how do I assign the @result variable  to have a value of 0? the count is based off a TransactionDate. If not entry's exist for the specified date range in the TransactionRemote table the the count() currently returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I needed to isnull() around the @AdjudicatedTotal cast to account for the possibility of a null value.

Set @SQLSG7 = ' Select '' '' As Portal, ''Confirmations (' + @SGProgramTypeDetailsConfirmed + ')' + ''' As Item, ''' + convert(varchar(10),(cast(@SGConfirmedCount as int)+isnull(cast(@AdjudicatedTotal as int), 0))) +''' As Value '